# CloudWatch Logs Insights Parse Syntax

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Lambda which queries the ec2 api and prints output to cloudwatch logs, which I want to use for metrics. However, I'm having trouble parsing the output (generated from a dictionary). Here is a typical @message:

`defaultdict(None, {ec2.Instance(id='i-instance'): {'InstanceID': 'i-instance', 'Type': 't2.micro', 'ImageID': 'ami-0e5493310d2c6de5b', 'State': 'running'`

I tried to `|parse 'InstanceID': *' as InstanceId` and similar but this errors, and I haven't found examples in the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html).

Assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can modify the Lambda, probably the simplest solution would be to print the dictionary as a one-line JSON (instead of Python dictionary's string format) - something like `print(json.dumps(myvalue))` should do the trick. Cloudwatch will then understand the fields automatically.

If you can't modify the Lambda's output, adding more quotes to the Logs Insights query might help: `parse @message "'InstanceID': '*'" as InstanceID`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using log insight the followings will give you instance id

```
fields @timestamp, @message, responseElements.instancesSet.items.0.instanceId as instanceId
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with this link:
[Fields in JSON logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html#CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-JSON-logs)